# openthread/environment docker rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted

Tags: openthread

I am running openthread/environment:latest docker image (as of 2019-06-15)

When starting on a fresh ubuntu 18.04 with docker 18.09 using the command

> ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-198:~$ docker run -it --rm openthread/environment bash

I get the following output

> - Stopping system message bus dbus                            [ OK ]
> - Starting system message bus dbus                            [ OK ]
> - Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd
>
> rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted
>
> rsyslogd: activation of module imklog failed [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]

Anyone knows whether this is related to ubuntu setup or the docker container or how to fix.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try adding the `--privileged` option.

For example:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged openthread/environment bash
```

Comment: Some users question why I have accepted this answer. The reason is that I am using an already build container, from a source I trust. The other answers I have seen, suggest to modify `Dockerfile` or the container. Just adding `--priviliged` works perfect for my workflow.

Comment: wrong answer, unless you really want the kernel logs. You can build your own Docker image based on top of a third part docker image, via `FROM anotherdockerimage:latest` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: This issue seems to apply to [Proxmox's unprivileged containers](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Linux_Container#pct_settings)

Answer (score 32):

@Reto's answer will work, but you will be editing that file every time you build your container. Put this in your `Dockerfile` and you're all set. The edit will be performed automatically while the container is being built.

```
RUN sed -i '/imklog/s/^/#/' /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Comment: If it is a complement to another user's answer, please leave a comment attached to said answer.

Comment: It's not a complement,  but rather a way to implement the solution in a not-ephemeral way. The given answer suggests manually editing a file in a Docker container. Containers are ephemeral. I think beginners are likely to wonder why the solution doesn't "stick". What's the right way to provide this extension to the answer? I thought it would be best to post it as an answer, with credit to the (necessary) predecessor.

Comment: Nothing in the [Reto Char's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58950678/52499) suggests that the change is to be performed manually. The answer is just not too specific about how to achieve that ;)

Comment: No. 
To be clear, I appreciate @Reto's insight. It helped me! But, if you know Docker, you know that editing files *inside* a container is a smell. Fix the problem *while the container is being built*. You can't get "inside" the Docker container while the Dockerfile is being run. It doesn't exist yet. The distinction here is important for people new to Docker. Until images and containers really click, it seems to make sense to edit things in containers.

Answer (score 22):

You will also get rid of this warning if you just comment out the line

```
module(load="imklog")
```

inside your Docker container (edit /etc/rsyslog.conf).

I doubt you want to read the kernel messages inside a container ;-)

Comment: This Answer should be the accepted one the accepted answer should explain that if you really want to give access to the host system then `privileged` is the right way.

One remark to this answer, for me, the format of the `rsyslog.conf` was different. I ended up doing: `sed -i 's/$ModLoad imklog.so/# $ModLoad imklog.so/' /etc/rsyslog.conf`

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. It suggests manually editing a system file in a Docker container. Containers are ephemeral and this suggested edit needs to be made every time the container is built. @braindongle's (my) answer below simply has `sed` perform this same edit for you when your Dockerfile is being run.

Comment: To make it clear, even with this line `rsyslog` starts.