# /etc/rc* not running on Ubuntu 18.04 in Docker. Cannot start cron on boot

Tags: docker, ubuntu, init.d

I can't seem to convince the `cron` (or any other) service to start with my Ubuntu container. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

I've tried using both `update-rc.d` and `/etc/rc.local` but no joy.

In this example `Dockerfile` I'm also trying to get `rsyslog` running in order to debug, with the same result- the service does not start.

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental

FROM ubuntu:18.04


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --reinstall -y \
    rsyslog

# fix for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609182/openthread-environment-docker-rsyslogd-imklog-cannot-open-kernel-log-proc-km
RUN sed -i '/imklog/s/^/#/' /etc/rsyslog.conf

# run at startup
RUN update-rc.d rsyslog defaults

# ...really run at startup
RUN echo "service rsyslog start" >> /etc/rc.local

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    cron

# run at startup
RUN update-rc.d cron defaults

# ...really run at startup
RUN echo "service cron start" >> /etc/rc.local

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

When I run the container:

```
root@e392a9404e0f:/# service --status-all
 [ - ]  cron
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsyslog
root@e392a9404e0f:/# service cron start
 * Starting periodic command scheduler cron                                                                             [ OK ] 
root@e392a9404e0f:/# service --status-all
 [ + ]  cron
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsyslog
```

Comment: Docker containers don't typically run init systems or `/etc/init.d` scripts; running `service` commands is likely to fail in several ways.  A container will generally run _one_ process as a foreground process and absolutely nothing else; that process usually isn't an interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

Add CMD to your Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

As init, the program is responsible for system initialization.
Read more about init [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/s2-boot-init-shutdown-init)

Comment: Thanks- I've learned something, but still stuck. The `ubuntu:18.04` base image seems pretty pared down. There's no `/sbin/init` and indeed no `/lib/systemd/systemd` , just a `/lib/systemd/system` directory, which has no obvious executable in it, but does at least contain files for `rsyslog` and `cron`.

Comment: By changing the puzzle to "why doesn't `/sbin/init` exist?" this got to a solution (see accepted answer). Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

systemd is not in the ubuntu docker images, by design

This is because its role as PID 1 is effectively replaced by docker's entrypoint

For more, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39169889/1892116

So the correct solution is what I thought was a hack. In my `entrypoint.sh` I have:

```
service rsyslog start
service cron start
```